# Its taking too much time for copying files into pendrive

Tags: files, clipboard, transfer, usb-drive

I'm Using Ubuntu 11.10, please help me.

Its taking too much time for me to copy files onto my pendrive.
Same pendrive is working at an acceptable transfer rate in Windows.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107703/why-is-my-pc-freezing-while-im-copying-a-file-to-a-pendrive

Answer (score 1):

If your pen drive is a USB 1.0 one then it's bandwidth cannot exceed 1 MB/s, if it's a usb 2.0 one then 600Megabitspersec , please report your current transfer rate.And if its read files with the same speed as it does for writing then your pen drive is all right.

Comment: usb 2.0 has 480mbit/s at maximum, not 600. also, many cheap usb sticks are just painfully slow.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have a faulty BIOS configuration. Check `dmesg` for error messages, too.